# Is there a way to conditionally change the state of a collapsible field group in admin, ie without changing a template or module file?

Tags: entities

I want to move the Metatags, keywords and edit summary into collapsible field groups at the top of the node edit page, but keep it open the first time the node is created, but collapsed in subsequent edits.

Can some CSS or Javascript be used to accomplish that? I don't want to do it in the file system code, whether are module or a template file.. I'd prefer something using the Admin even if it means applying some PHP there. If a module like the Context module can be used to test whether it is a newly created record and change some settings that will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by applying PHP 'in the Admin' but you could add a hook to template.php in your admin theme.

```
function mytheme_form_node_form_alter(&$form) {
  if (!$form['nid']['#value']) {
    $form['myfieldset']['#collapsed'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

If you'd rather go with a JS solution the following should work.

```
(function ($){
  Drupal.behaviors.dynamicCollapsedFieldset = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('.page-node-add #myfieldset').once('dynamic-collapsed-fieldset').removeClass('collapsed');
    }
  }
}(jQuery));
```

You'd need to attach the JS in a file either in a module (which you said you want to avoid) or in your admin theme's .info file.

Unless you're using a custom admin theme I'd strongly advise against hacking core / contrib to implement either method. Either create a subtheme or a small module for this.

Edit:

Here's a version checking for a fieldset prefix

```
function mytheme_form_node_form_alter(&$form) {
  if (!$form['nid']['#value']) {
    foreach ($form as $key => $value) {
      if (strpos($key, 'group_metatags_') === 0) {
        $form[$key]['#collapsed'] = FALSE;    
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I named the field group `group metatags' but field group names can't be shared across content types. Is there some kind of regex match I could use to locate the metatags field groups on all content types if they were named 'group_metatags_xxxx'

Comment: I've added an example of this to my solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be open on page creation, you can target the page using the node-add-CONTENTTYPE class on the body. Using some jQuery in document ready you can set it open.

Something like:

```
jQuery('body.page-node-add-<YOUR-CONTENT-TYPE> fieldset.#YOUR-ID-HERE').removeClass('collapsed').children('.fieldset-wrapper').show();
```

Comment: all though your suggestion resembles gigabates version it didn't work. I used code per node module to apply it. Is it an exact answer or a pointer to a solution?

Comment: A pointer but you should only need to identify the machine name of the content type and the fieldset's ID (unless metatag module has different HTML structure).

Gigabates solution is convoluted for something so simple. It wouldn't be nice from a maintenance perspective. For example, you don't need to use drupal behaviors unless it's an ajax form.